# How to read from an os.pipe() without getting blocked?

Tags: python, file, pipe

I'm trying to read from an open `os.pipe()` to see if it's empty at the moment of the reading. The problem is that calling `read()` causes the program to block there until there is actually something to read there however there won't be any, if the test I'm doing succeeded.

I know I can use `select.select()` with a timeout however I wanted to know if there is another solution to the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might try this.

```
import os, fcntl
fcntl.fcntl(thePipe, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

With this `thePipe.read()` should be non-blocking.

From [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) man page:

> If a process attempts to read from an
>   empty pipe, then read(2) will block
>   until data is available. (...)
>   Non-blocking I/O is possible by using
>   the fcntl(2) `F_SETFL` operation to
>   enable the `O_NONBLOCK` open file status
>   flag.

Comment: beware: file methods such as `.readline()` might not expect a non-blocking mode.

Comment: Interesting, for binary pipe sys.stdin.buffer.read() it doesn't seem to block by default. Returns with no items.